# FCM based push notification not clickable on android Firefox

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

While implemented firebase push notification as described on [URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) , It working fine in WEB & WAP of chrome and WEB of Firefox but in WAP of firefox, the notification received fine but on clicking, nothing works not even open FF browser.
For click event, I have sent 'click_action' on the payload. Please suggest..